# Disable some years from an array of strings in YearPicker Material-Ui and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue with disable some years from Material-Ui YearPicker.
I extracted from my database an array containing the dates that I would like to disable as follows:

```
const singleYearsArray = itemList.map(element => element.year)
setSingleYears(singleYearsArray)
```

now I have to tell YearPicker to disable all years in that array.
I found the "shouldDisableYear" prop. in the documentation [MUI Doc](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/year-picker/) but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation it looks like you should use it like this:

```
shouldDisableYear={(year) => singleYearsArray.includes(year)}
```

This will tell the picker to disable each year which is contained in your singleYearsArray  list.
Keep in mind that types of "year" as input paramter in callback must be the same as type of year in your list.

Comment: Hi Milos and thanks for your suggestion. I tried your exact suggestion and also some variations but to no avail.

Comment: Hey Claudio, I played with it on codesandbox and found out that year that is provided as input parameter is not a number, but a DateTime object(which is pretty dumb). So you should rewrite it to `shouldDisableYear={(year) => singleYearsArray.includes(new Date(year).getFullYear())}` . And just be sure that your list also contains only numbers, and not strings.